# Dedicated chat room for Harry Potter and the Cursed Child Parts I and II

Tags: discussion

The eighth installment of the *Harry Potter* series opens as a play on, I believe, August 1st. J.K. Rowling has stated *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child Parts I and II* is canon. Therefore, I thought a chat room dedicated to discussion of the new play, as well as prior canon, would be in order. I've created a chat room: [**Harry Potter and the #%$@^# Child**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43168/harry-potter-and-the-child).

Please note that this chat room is ***NOT*** spoiler free. In fact, spoilers may abound! Spoiler-free talk regarding *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child Parts I and II* should be held in our regular chat room, [**Mos Eisley**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley).

Questions? Thoughts?

**ETA:** From the Wikipedia's entry on *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*: *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child, a two part play, was written by British playwright Jack Thorne based on an original story by Thorne, John Tiffany and J.K. Rowling. Some Web sites were listing all three as authors of the script [27] but by 26 July 2016, the official web site for the play [28] and many others (including the BBC)[29] were listing [Jack] Thorne as the sole script writer.*

If the play was written by Jack Thorne, and J.K. Rowling maybe served in more of a consulting role, for example, is *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child Parts I and II* still as canon as if J.K. Rowling herself had written it? Rowling has insisted *Cursed Child* is canon ... I don't know! Guess I'd better get over to my own chat room to dish it!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I shall lurk. You might want to start compiling a list of questions that are likely to be answered by the play.

Comment: As a room-owner, you might also want to star-sticky a reminder in Mos Eisley that people should avoid saying spoilers and change the room title to reflect that as well.

Comment: The plot has been around online ever since the first preview showing two months ago.

Comment: @ibid -- Are you just making a stand-alone statement re: the plot, or did you have another point in mind? The plot may be known, but many people stay successfully spoiler-free by being careful about what they do or do not read online or elsewhere. :)

Comment: the rehearsal draft of the script is released for print on July 31. 
The play opened for previews in June in London.

Comment: @Slytherincess - My point was that nothing really is changing now. If we were making a spoiler chatroom, then it should have been made two months ago.

Comment: @ibid -- Well, regardless of your objection regarding who may wish to be spoiled when, my point was to create a dedicated space for discussing *Cursed Child*. People are free to dish spoilers, or not. It's meant to be all in good fun. Perhaps the room was created too late; no one else created one earlier, though. I say, hey, if you think something should have been done in a certain way or time frame, then you certainly could have set it up. Otherwise, it's kind of impolite to bag on someone else who bothered to try. :)